# Python Tkinter callbackfunction executes before mainloop

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I'm trying to build a gui for communication with a serial device. For this I'm using Tkinter. My problem is, that every time I execute the script only the estCon-function is executed and the mainloop, and therefore the gui is never started. If I place the definition of the estCon function after the main loop it says that the estCon function was not found.

```
def estCon():
    # establish connection
    while True:
        try:
            ser = serial.Serial(port, baud, bytesize)
            print('Connected.')
            break
        except serial.SerialException:
            print('waiting for device ' + port + ' to be available.') 
            time.sleep(3)

    starttime = time.time()
    outfile = open(filename, 'a')
    doprint = True    

root = Tk()

estConButton = Button(root, text="Establish serial connection",
                      command=estCon())
estConButton.pack()

root.mainLoop()
```

Comment: So is it printing out anything or just sitting there?

Comment: jap, the estCon function is immediately executed and it's printing the "waiting for device" expression

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change this line:

```
estConButton = Button(root, text="Establish serial connection", command=estCon())
```

To:

```
estConButton = Button(root, text="Establish serial connection", command=estCon)
```

Notice the lack of parentheses `()`. Basically, you need to pass a reference to the function that will be called when you press the button and not an actual call.